# Navigate to anchor on error message

Tags: php, html

I have this little contact form manager and it displays an error message as an array. I need that every time the error message appears, the user goes down to an anchor in my page.

The code looks like this:

```
$errors = array();

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)=== false){
    $errors[] = 'Invalid email';

  }
  if (ctype_alpha($name)===false){
    $errors[] = 'Invalid name';

  }
  if (ctype_alpha($phone)===true){
    $errors[] = 'Invalid number';

  }
```

Besides showing the message, how can I send the user to an anchor in the site?

The only way so far I got it to work was by using:

```
<script>
    window.location = 'sent.php';
</script>
```

But I can't use that everytime the user gets an error, or can I?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I couldn't use the header tag with this array because the result for the array was an empty one, so I managed to do something like this at the index where the error message was posted.

```
 <?php                                                                  

   if (empty($errors)===false) {  
     echo'<ul>';

        foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo '<li style="color:red; font-weight:bolder; 
        text-decoration:none;">'
        ,$error, '</li>';                                        
    } 

    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</br>';

    ?>

    <script>
    window.location = '#correoA';
    </script>

    <?php

}                                                                                ?>
```

So this way I get the error message and the window location